# Unable to create customer Account using SoftLayer Branding APi

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have a partner account in SoftLayer. While creating a customer tenant/account using softlayer branding API through partner credential it shows "You don't have such permissions"- Can you please tell me what I need to perform to grant the concern permission ?

Also can you please guide me for the following aspects :
1. Can we create multiple tenant/ customer account for a single customer in SoftLayer ? If No then which field should be treated as a unique for individual customers
2. Can we get Order's all billable(RAM, CPU etc.) item usage daily basis ? (usage in term of used amount and price/unit   )

Answer (score 0):

the Branding API creates new accounts, if you are able to create the new account in the  https://agent.softlayer.com/ portal you should be able to create it via API, if you get the same issue in the portal, I suggest you to submit a ticket to Softlayer.

check this example about create accounts for brands. https://softlayer.github.io/python/create_account/

regardin your questions:
1.- You can create several accounts for the brands.
2.- Usin API there is no a method wich return the usage daily, but you can see your invoices take a look at this code https://gist.github.com/underscorephil/5861175

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the information, So as per the answer of Question 1, I can create multiple account / tenant for a single customer. So if we consider an enterprise service provider model then a service provider can create multiple account/ tenant for a single customer -- is it correct ?

Comment: The brand account can have multiple accounts, I suggest you to talk with someone from sonftlayer sales, they can answer better these questions.